# Load two templates in the same *ngIf else condition

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is a material layout table that loads data from a component. As a condition for loading a button template, it is necessary to inform a column with the name of that template, then the ngIf condition is fulfilled as requested:

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="tableData !== 'action'; else action"> <!--condition is ok -->
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{ columnHeader[tableData] }}
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[tableData] }}</td>
    </ng-container>
```

Template loads correctly and renders:

```
    <ng-template #action>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          bla bla bla action
      </td>
    </ng-template>
```

All I need is to load this other template at the same time, but nested doesn't work and I don't know how to get both templates to load in ngIf:

```
 <!--the template not loading-->
    <ng-template #activity>
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          bla bla bla activity
    </td>
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: [edit] and change language to english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*ngTemplateOutlet` to render another template, passing the template reference variable into it.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="tableData !== 'action'; else action"> 
  <h1>hello</h1>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #action>
  <h1>hello again</h1>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="activity"></ng-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #activity>
  <h1>world again</h1>
</ng-template>
```

Working example:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-l596t2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html